# pandas compare row with another row and make desire value for remaining value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
num=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-1,2,3,4,5,6,]
    df=pd.DataFrame(num)
    df['i_want_that']=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    print(df)


   0  i_want_that
0   1            1
1   2            2
2   3            3
3   4            4
4   5            5
5   6            6
6   7            7
7   8            8
8  -1           -1
9  -1            0
10 -1            0
11 -1            0
12 -1            0
13 -1            0
```

if  '0' value is -1  then all remaining row will be zero  sometime 
-1 can come in any row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `cumprod` on the boolean mask of `df[0] != -1`.  It will be one until it hits the first `-1` at which point it multiplies by `False` and turns to zero.  Once it's zero, it stays zero.  Then multiply this by `df[0]`.  However, I shift this to capture the first `-1` value.

```
df.assign(new=df[0].ne(-1).shift().fillna(True).cumprod().mul(df[0]))


    0  new
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    3
3   4    4
4   5    5
5   6    6
6   7    7
7   8    8
8  -1   -1
9   2    0
10  3    0
11  4    0
12  5    0
13  6    0
```

---

You can improve performance by utilizing the underlying numpy arrays

```
v = df[0].values
df.assign(new=v * np.append(True, v[:-1] != -1).cumprod())

    0  new
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    3
3   4    4
4   5    5
5   6    6
6   7    7
7   8    8
8  -1   -1
9   2    0
10  3    0
11  4    0
12  5    0
13  6    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for index of first `-1` and then overwrite all values from this index to the end of column `0` with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print((df[0] == -1).idxmax())
8

df.loc[(df[0] == -1).idxmax():, 0] = 0
print (df)
    0  i_want_that
0   1            1
1   2            2
2   3            3
3   4            4
4   5            5
5   6            6
6   7            7
7   8            8
8   0            0
9   0            0
10  0            0
11  0            0
12  0            0
13  0            0
```

Another solution is get boolean mask by [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and then overwrite values by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
mask = (df[0] == -1).cumsum() != 0
print (mask)
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool

df['new'] = df[0].mask(mask, 0)
print (df)
    0  i_want_that  new
0   1            1    1
1   2            2    2
2   3            3    3
3   4            4    4
4   5            5    5
5   6            6    6
6   7            7    7
7   8            8    8
8  -1            0    0
9   2            0    0
10  3            0    0
11  4            0    0
12  5            0    0
13  6            0    0
```

Comment: can i select the -1 value after new[8] and after that 0 just like my edit example

Comment: You can add `1` - `df.loc[(df[0] == -1).idxmax() + 1:, 0] = 0`

Comment: and for second solution `mask = ((df[0] == -1).cumsum() != 0).shift()`
`mask.iloc[0] = False`